# Valgrind: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" in math functions

Tags: c++, valgrind

I cannot find what is causing the conditional jumps in my C++ program. I am testing it with Valgrind 3.11.0 and the program is compiled with gcc 5.4.0.

The issue is that these conditional jumps seem to occur in trigonometric functions using AVX instructions but also with `sqrt()` functions, not in my code. Below I paste the Valgrind messages:

```
==29490== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29490==    at 0x54436DD: __sin_avx (s_sin.c:482)
...

==29490== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29490==    at 0x54449D4: __cos_avx (s_sin.c:597)
...
==28458== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28458==    at 0x543F7B7: __ieee754_atan2_avx (e_atan2.c:434)
==28458==    by 0x53F746F: atan2 (w_atan2.c:36)
...

==29490== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29490==    at 0x53F8258: sqrt (w_sqrt.c:27)
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [repro] demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like `atan2` compare the arguments against some constants internally (e.g., `if (x < 0) ...`). If what you have passed is has an uninitialized value, valgrind will rightly complain (try for example `double x, y; atan2(x, y);`). The problem is not in the math functions but with the caller.

You need to make sure the arguments are properly initialized, which may be nontrivial as the uninitialized values may spread from unexpected places. Try compiling your code with debug symbols to see if valgrind can print a more detailed backtrace.

Comment: As you said, it was hard to find but the problem was caused by an uninitialized element in an array.